# FASTA reader written in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, genetic-algorithm, fasta

Let me start off by stating that I am a beginner in C++. Anyways, the FASTA format goes as follows: 
Any line starting with a '>' indicates the name/id of the gene sequence right below it. There is a gene sequence right below the id. This gene sequence can be 1 or multiple lines. 
So... what I want to do is print:  id << " : " << gene_sequence << endl;

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << " Wrong format: " << argv[0] << " [infile] " << std::endl;
        return -1;
}

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if (!input.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening: " << argv[1] << " . You have failed." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::string line, id, DNA_sequence;
    while (std::getline(input, line).good()) {
        if (line[0] == '>') {
            id = line.substr(1);
            std::cout << id << " : " << DNA_sequence << std::endl;
            DNA_sequence.clear();
        }
        else if (line[0] != '>'){
            DNA_sequence += line;
        }
    }
}
```

For the second argument inputted into the command line, here is the content of my file:

```
>DNA_1
GATTACA
>DNA_2
TAGACCA
TAGACCA
>DNA_3
ATAC
>DNA_4
AT
```

Please copy and paste into text file. 
After this has been done, and the code has been executed, I want to point out the problem. The code skips inputting the sequence of DNA_1 into its correct respective place, and instead placing DNA_1 's sequence into DNA_2. The results get pushed forward 1 as a result. Any assistance or tips would be greatly appreciated? 
As I've said before, I am new to C++. And the semantics are quite hard to learn compared to Python.

Answer (score 4):

I see a few problems with your code.

First you loop on `std::ifstream::good()` which doesn't work because it won't allow for End Of File (which happens even after a good read).

Then you access `line[0]` without checking if the line is empty which could cause a seg-fault.

Next you output the "previous line" before you have even collected it.

Finally you don't output the final line because the loop terminates when it doesn't find another `>`.

I added comments to my corrections to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << " Wrong format: " << argv[0] << " [infile] " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if (!input.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening: " << argv[1] << " . You have failed." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::string line, id, DNA_sequence;

    // Don't loop on good(), it doesn't allow for EOF!!

//    while (std::getline(input, line).good()) {
      while (std::getline(input, line)) {

        // line may be empty so you *must* ignore blank lines
        // or you have a crash waiting to happen with line[0]
        if(line.empty())
            continue;

        if (line[0] == '>') {
            // output previous line before overwriting id
            // but ONLY if id actually contains something
            if(!id.empty())
                std::cout << id << " : " << DNA_sequence << std::endl;

            id = line.substr(1);
            DNA_sequence.clear();
        }
        else {//  if (line[0] != '>'){ // not needed because implicit
            DNA_sequence += line;
        }
    }

    // output final entry
    // but ONLY if id actually contains something
    if(!id.empty())
        std::cout << id << " : " << DNA_sequence << std::endl;

}
```

**Output:**

```
DNA_1 : GATTACA
DNA_2 : TAGACCATAGACCA
DNA_3 : ATAC
DNA_4 : AT
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the new id before printing the old one:

```
id = line.substr(1);
std::cout << id << " : " << DNA_sequence << std::endl;
```

Swap the lines around for proper order. You probably also want to check if you have any id already present to skip the first entry.

Comment: Thanks, partially. The swap made the gene sequences go correctly with their id. But now the first line prints only a " : ", which I understand, because there is no id or gene sequence at the very beginning of the loop. Then the next three lines are DNA_1: [sequence], DNA_2: [sequence], DNA_3: [sequence] . So DNA_4 and its sequence has been omitted.

Comment: You're not getting `>` after the last line, so you have to do the last print after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

working implementation is here
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/FASTA_format#C.2B.2B

only corrected

```
while( std::getline( input, line ).good() ){
```

to

```
while( std::getline( input, line ) ){
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    if( argc <= 1 ){
        std::cerr << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" [infile]" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if(!input.good()){
        std::cerr << "Error opening '"<<argv[1]<<"'. Bailing out." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string line, name, content;
    while( std::getline( input, line ) ){
        if( line.empty() || line[0] == '>' ){ // Identifier marker
            if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
                std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
                name.clear();
            }
            if( !line.empty() ){
                name = line.substr(1);
            }
            content.clear();
        } else if( !name.empty() ){
            if( line.find(' ') != std::string::npos ){ // Invalid sequence--no spaces allowed
                name.clear();
                content.clear();
            } else {
                content += line;
            }
        }
    }
    if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
        std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
>Rosetta_Example_1 
THERECANBENOSPACE
>Rosetta_Example_2 
THERECANBESEVERAL 
LINESBUTTHEYALLMUST
BECONCATENATED
```

output:

```
Rosetta_Example_1 : THERECANBENOSPACE
Rosetta_Example_2 : THERECANBESEVERALLINESBUTTHEYALLMUSTBECONCATENATED
```